# C23 Vector Macro Implementation

Tags: c, vectors, macros

I'm trying to implement a simple type-generic Vector with macros using the newest features of C23. Looking for any advice about macro design and pitfalls because I generally avoid macros at all costs. Wondering how to extend this code to handle more complex data types as well.

Also, I'm not particularly happy with the hacky `int vector_abort()` used in the `vector_at()` ternary. Any portable advice here is greatly appreciated. Furthermore, if anyone has a way to make opaque structures with macros I would be very interested.

A major problem that I immediately notice is that there isn't an easy way to tell if `vector_push()` was successful. However, return values aren't permitted for macros and calling `abort()` or `exit()` doesn't seem great in this instance.

### C23 features used:

- `nullptr` constant from `<stddef.h>`
- `true` and `false` keywords
- `free_sized()` from `<stdlib.h>`
- `= {}` empty initializer
- `function()` empty function argument declaration
- `typeof` operator
- `N3003` Improved Rules for Tag Compatibility

### vector.h

```c
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

#include <errno.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int vector_abort(void) {
  errno = EINVAL;
  fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s.\n" "Invalid vector index.\n", strerror(errno));
  errno = 0;
  abort();
  return 0;
}

#define vector(TYPE) struct vector_##TYPE {size_t length; size_t capacity; TYPE* array;}

#define vector_new(TYPE, CAPACITY) {.length = 0, .capacity = CAPACITY, .array = calloc(CAPACITY, sizeof(TYPE))}

#define vector_delete(VECTOR)                                             \
do {                                                                      \
  VECTOR.length = 0;                                                      \
  VECTOR.capacity = 0;                                                    \
  free_sized(VECTOR.array, (VECTOR.length * sizeof(*(VECTOR.array))));    \
  VECTOR.array = nullptr;                                                 \
} while (false)

#define vector_size(VECTOR) VECTOR.length

#define vector_at(VECTOR, INDEX) (VECTOR.length > INDEX) ? VECTOR.array[INDEX] : vector_abort()

#define vector_pop(VECTOR) if (VECTOR.length > 0) VECTOR.length--

#define vector_push(VECTOR, VALUE)                                                                              \
do {                                                                                                            \
  if (VECTOR.length == VECTOR.capacity) {                                                                       \
    typeof(VECTOR.array) new_array = realloc(VECTOR.array, (VECTOR.capacity * 2 * sizeof(*(VECTOR.array))));    \
    if (!new_array) break;                                                                                      \
    VECTOR.capacity *= 2;                                                                                       \
    VECTOR.array = new_array;                                                                                   \
  }                                                                                                             \
  VECTOR.array[VECTOR.length] = VALUE;                                                                          \
  VECTOR.length++;                                                                                              \
} while (false)

#endif
```

### main.c

```c
#include "./vector.h"

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  vector(int) v = {};   // or use = vector_new(type, capacity)
  vector_push(v, 1);
  vector_push(v, 2);
  vector_push(v, 3);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < vector_size(v); ++i) {
    printf("Test Push %d\n", vector_at(v, i));
  }
  vector_pop(v);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < vector_size(v); ++i) {
    printf("Test Pop %d\n", vector_at(v, i));
  }
  vector_delete(v);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < vector_size(v); ++i) {
    printf("Test Delete %d\n", vector_at(v, i));
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Polyfill

Here is a `free_sized()` polyfill if your implementation doesn't support it yet.

```c
void free_sized(void* ptr, size_t /*size*/) {
  free(ptr);
}
```

### Compiler Flags

`-Wall` `-Wextra` `-Werror` `-pedantic-errors` `-std=c2x`

Comment: Your `vector_delete` appears to use the `length` field after it is set to 0 in a call to `free_sized`. I believe it should be using `capacity` not `length`, and should be using them before setting them to zero. (Which, if they're both set to zero it doesn't really matter which you use, does it? But still...)

Comment: @aghast Nice catch. The free_sized() polyfill prevented the compiler from warning me about that bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Improve macro safety

You seem to have hit the usual pitfalls of macros - remember these are *text substitutions* done by the C preprocessor, so we need to ensure that the the rules of precedence don't give an unexpected meaning to the expansion.

For example, consider `vector_pop`:

> ```
> #define vector_pop(VECTOR) if (VECTOR.length > 0) VECTOR.length--
> ```

Since `.` binds very tightly and `if` can catch a following `else`, we really need extra parens and a `do`/`while (0)`:

```
#define vector_pop(VECTOR) \
    do { if ((VECTOR).length > 0) (VECTOR).length--; } while (false)
```

Similarly, `vector_size` should be defined to expand to `((VECTOR).length)` rather than to the much less safe `VECTOR.length`.

---

## Improve the "abort" function

Shouldn't `vector_abort()` be `static`?  At present, it seems that we'll get a definition in each translation unit that includes the header, causing link-time errors.

This function has an unreachable `return` statement.  The assignment of  `errno = 0` doesn't have any discernable value - unless you have a signal handler that uses it, which seems a poor choice.

I'd write:

```
static _Noreturn void vector_abort(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s.\nInvalid vector index.\n", strerror(EINVAL));
    abort();
}
```

---

## Handle allocation failures correctly

`vector_push` provides no feedback when `realloc()` fails - the calling program is required to test the vector size before and after (this checking is conspicuously absent from the demo program, suggesting others will forget this too).

`vector_new` violates the invariant (that `array[capacity-1]` is valid) whenever `calloc()` fails.

Comment: `vector_abort()` cannot be a void statement because it is used in the `vector_at()` ternary

Comment: Ah yes - it probably instead needs a comment explaining why the unreachable `return` is present, to help readers like me!

Comment: @Biggs Note: `_Noreturn` function specifier is deprecated. `[[noreturn]]` attribute should be used instead. The macro `noreturn` is also deprecated. (Since C23)

Comment: @Haris As stated before, `[[noreturn]]` would cause undefined behavior if applied to a function with a return statement. The function must return due to its use in a ternary statement. Good catch though about the new syntax

Comment: @Biggs, it's perfectly fine for a `[[noreturn]]` function to have a return type, as long as it doesn't actually reach a `return`.  See [_Can I use `[[noreturn]]` on non-void returning functions?_](//stackoverflow.com/q/38623143/4850040)  That's a C++ question, but the same reasoning applies to C.